# Explaination on Javascript code required

Tags: javascript, html, webview

I wanted to know if anybody can explain me the following piece of Javascript Code:

```
   j1 = {};
   j1.version = "0.0.1";
   j1.port = "0";
   j1.key = "DEFAULT_KEY"; //default random key  
   j1.requestID = 1000;
   j1.setPort = function (port) {
       this.port = port;
   };

   j1.setKey = function (key) {
       this.key = key;
   };

   j1.onDeviceReady = function () {};
   j1.onPushNotification = function (message) {};

   j1.platform = {};
   j1.platform.WINDOWS_PHONE = "WINDOWS_PHONE";
   j1.platform.IOS = "IOS";
   j1.platform.BLACKBERRY = "BLACKBERRY";
   j1.platform.ANDROID = "ANDROID";

   // Device  
   j1.device = {
       name: "",
       version: "",
       platform: "",
       uuid: "",
       initDevice: function (deviceName, deviceVersion, devicePlatform, deviceUUID) {
           this.name = deviceName;
           this.version = deviceVersion;
           this.platform = devicePlatform;
           this.uuid = deviceUUID;
       }
   };
```

This is in terms of a hybrid mobile web application.

Thanks
sneha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

j1 is an **object literal**. An object literal is a comma-separated list of property key/value pairs enclosed in curly braces. You can read more about those [here](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/obj_lit.php) or [here](http://www.brainonfire.net/blog/javascript-object-literal-namespace/).

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to explain anything here since the code only provides some structure. It doesn't really do anything interesting.

Answer (score -2):

j1 is an object which has some properties. It is using json (javascript object notation http://www.json.org/)

Comment: There is no JSON involved here. It's just plain old JavaScript.

Comment: duh - I meant object literal! although there are some similarities